# Continued fractions and product-integrals in calculus textbooks [soft-question]

Tags: calculus, soft-question, continued-fractions

Why are continued fractions and product-integrals (Volterra type) missing from so many modern calculus textbooks? They are such nice concepts, complementing "superstars" like series, products or the Riemann integral.

Comment: Have you ever taught calculus to a room full of 18-year-olds?   Why put in material that you'll never have time to cover or an audience to hear?